# Is is possible to get Visual Studio Code to "ignore" the first click on macOS, and not move the cursor?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Pretty much all applications on macOS have the ability to "ignore" the first click used to focus the window. This allows you to focus a window without carefully finding someplace safe to click on (ie not a button or a text area).

Currently on VS Code, when I click anywhere in a text area, the cursor moves to where I clicked, even if the window wasn't focused. Is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: While you say that the other apps have the ability, are you saying that your own apps actually do this? Which apps? Because this sounds like an OS behavior, not an application behavior.

Comment: Most apps have this behavior. For example, I just opened Pages, pasted a bunch of text, unfocused the window, and clicked somewhere in the document. The cursor did not go to the place I clicked. It did when I clicked a second time though (because the window was already focused). Just tried Safari too, same behavior.

Comment: Some apps do register some clicks, so it seems that it is up to the developer to choose what clicks to register and what to ignore.

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing you'll need to submit a bug or request on the VSCode GitHub regarding this. Basically, the OS offers certain hooks or calls to applications, which then can choose which of these to connect to and therefore how they behave. If VS Code doesn't already support this, it would require development work to add the function.

Comment: I was hoping it already had the feature but you're right it is probably a good idea to ask on GitHub.

Answer (score 8):

There is an item in Settings > User > Window called "Click Through Inactive" that will let you change this.

[image: click through inactive setting]

Comment: you have no idea how long i've been searching for this! the focus on first click in vscode has bothered me for so long! thank you @mjackson